# GWT: is it possible to set base URL as a parameter?

Tags: url, gwt, radix

I am trying to make GWT application work in a portlet. Portlet is a part of a page which is formed in a context, other that entire page.

This makes paths not working.

For example, and object

```
Image logo = new Image("images/online.png");
```

is rendered as

```
<img class="gwt-Image" src="images/online.png">
```

This path is correct in portlet context but wrong in root context.

Is it possible to make GWT to look for paths starting from getContextPath()? It would be great if it was possible to add some parameters into HTML code before main Javascrip insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` as a base for your URLs (possibly using `..` to move up); e.g.

```java
Image logo = new Image(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "../images/online.png");
```

As a rule of thumb, always make your URLs relative to either `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` or `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`.

You could of course also use `ClientBundle` and `ImageResource` to be deployment-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your GWT loader script where you want to load your other GWT files from. The GWT module URL is determined by the loader script's "src" attribute. So, if you need to add a prefix to your static file path - add the prefix to your loader script's:

```
<script src="prefix/xxx.yyy.Module.js" type="javascript/text"/>
```

GWT will load all files from the URL specified in this script tag

Comment: I guess this does not work. I am already loading script correctly. I.e. I am writing in my JSP to load script from 

    request.getContextPath() + "/mymodule/mymodule.nocache.js" 

and this is rendered in page source as 

    <script src="/myapp/mymodule/mymodule.nocache.js

i.e. correclty.

But images are still rendered as I said, i.e. without myapp path.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Window.Location.createUrlBuilder();` which gives you a UrlBuilder with the current URL and you can change the fragments via `urlBuilder.setParameter(..)`, `urlBuilder.setPath(..)`, `urlBuilder.setHost(..)`, etc.